# I accidentally saved over my save file. Can I recover it?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim, xbox-360

While playing as my low level character, I decided to play as my high levelled character instead. I went to load the game but selected Save instead of Load. I didn't notice until it had overwritten my save!

Is there a way to recover the save I deleted? I'm playing on Xbox 360 if that's relevant.

Answer (score 2):

Your only chance of restoring your save is to possibly have a previous auto-save file from the previous character, though depending on how long you have been playing on the new character, chances are the auto-save has been overwritten.

Answer (score 0):

Not without violating the terms of agreement.

There are ways to hack the hard drive, but i don't know anything about that other then the fact that it is not allowed by microsoft and that you may possible get your account banned if microsoft thinks that you hacked the drive/file to cheat in some way.

But no; xbox 360 does not have any function that allows you to restore deleted saves.